# I removed a Mezuzah without knowing what it is, what should I do?

Tags: mezuzah

**Background**:

Next to the door of a new flat there was a roll of paper inside some plastic wrap. I didn't know what it was, so I took it down to inspect it.

Inside I found a roll of very stiff paper and Hebrew writing. A quick Google search and I learn that this is a Mezuzah. I don't know much about the Jewish faith, and I don't want to cause any more harm then I may have already.

This is a rented flat, I believe the landlord had the Mezuzah placed there in accordance to their faith.

**Question**:

In such a case would a non-Jew be "qualified" to simply put the Mezuzah back where it was, or should something else be done with it?

(I was linked to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9598/scrolls-on-door-frames-what-are-they-called-and-what-should-i-do), which is very close to this one, the main difference being that I have removed the Mezuzah from its place, not know what it was until I looked it up on Google.)

Comment: I would contact your local Orthodox rabbi and ask him. This is a very tough subject I don't think anyone but your local rabbi could answer. (CYLOR)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I don't know the answer to your question off hand (but I'm pretty sure there is nothing more you can do right now), but have you asked the landlord? I don't think they'd mind if you explained what happened. Sounds like you made an honest mistake

Comment: I would just return it to the landlord as the fact that you are renting the apartment means that it does not need a mezuzah.

Answer (score 3):

There are special blessings said when one puts up a mezuzah. You should not put the mezuzah back up where it was, but rather place it somewhere safe and call up the landlord and tell them what you've done.

Comment: Do those blessings even apply when replacing a mezuzah, though?  Like when you take it down to have it inspected, or because you're painting?

Comment: This OP doesn't sound so Jewish. As such he would not be making blessings and he shouldn't be putting it up at all. Also @Monica as a nonjew his removal would be deemed one that would require a new blessing when it is put on by a jew. It is not comparable to a Jew who removed it with intention to return it to that place.

Comment: @user6591 the OP shouldn't be making a *b'racha* in any case.  I can't remember if a Jew makes a *b'racha* when replacing a *mezuzah* but if not, the question shouldn't even come up for a non-Jew.  But I didn't know that a non-Jew taking it down meant a *b'racha* would be required.  Rafael, assuming you concur, it'd be good to [edit] that into your answer.  (And if you can cite sources, even better.)

Comment: @Monica any time a mitzvah is interrupted with intention of continuing it no bracha is said. So taking off teffilin or a taalis or a mezuzah with intention to put it back gets no new bracha because it is considered a continuation of the old act. If the taalis tefilin or mezuzah fall off or are removed by someone who is not qualified to have the intention to 'continue' the mitzvah, then the old mitzvah is over and a blessing must be said when it is begun again and affixed anew.

Comment: @doubleAA considering the ambiguity regarding whether the mezuzah may have been forgotten by a previous tenant and that the landlord may not be religiously observant, I would think that the actual correct answer is the unfortunately deleted one to consult an Orthodox rabbi who is likely to treat the mezuzah appropriately.